# How to use volumes in Kubernetes deployments?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to use volumes for deployments with more than one replica. How do I define an `PersistentVolumeClaim` so it will be generated for each replica? At the moment (see example below) I am able to generate a volume and assign it to the pods. The problem is, that only one volume gets generated which causes this error messages:

```
  38m   1m  18  {kubelet worker-1.loc}      Warning FailedMount Unable to mount volumes for pod "solr-1254544937-zblou_default(610b157c-549e-11e6-a624-0238b97cfe8f)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "solr-1254544937-zblou"/"default". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[datadir]
  38m   1m  18  {kubelet worker-1.loc}      Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "solr-1254544937-zblou"/"default". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[datadir]
```

How can I tell Kubernetes to generate a volume for each replica?

I am using Kubernetes 1.3.

---

Example:

```yaml
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: solr-datadir
  annotations:
    volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: anything
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment

metadata:
  name: solr
  labels:
    team: platform
    tier: search
    app: solr

spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  replicas: 3

  template:
    metadata:
      name: solr
      labels:
        team: platform
        tier: search
        app: solr

    spec:
      containers:
      - name: solr
        image: solr:6-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 512m
            memory: 512Mi
        command: 
        - /bin/bash
        args:
        - -c
        - /opt/solr/bin/solr start -f -z zookeeper:2181
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores"
          name: datadir
      volumes:
      - name: datadir
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: solr-datadir
```

Generated pods:

```
$ kubectl get pods -lapp=solr 
NAME                    READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
solr-1254544937-chenr   1/1       Running             0          55m
solr-1254544937-gjud0   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          55m
solr-1254544937-zblou   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          55m
```

Generated volumes:

```
$ kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STATUS    CLAIM                         REASON    AGE
pvc-3955e8f1-549e-11e6-94be-060ea3314be5   50Gi       RWO           Bound     default/solr-datadir                    57m
```

Generated claims:

```
$ kubectl get pvc
NAME                  STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   AGE
solr-datadir          Bound     pvc-3955e8f1-549e-11e6-94be-060ea3314be5   0                        57m
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ReplicaSets treat volumes as stateless. If your replicaset pod template specifies a volume that can only be attached read-write once, then the same volume is used by all pods in that replicaset. If that volume can only be attached read-write to one node at a time (like GCE PDs), then after the first pod is successfully scheduled and started, subsequent instances of the pod will fail to start if they are scheduled to a different node, because the volume will not be able to attach to the second node.

What you are looking for is Pet Sets which enable you to generate a volume for each replica. See http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/ The feature is currently in alpha but should address your usecase.

**Update:** In Kubernetes 1.5+ PetSets were renamed to StatefulSets. See the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).

Comment: Note that Deployments currently only support Pods and Replica Sets, and not PetSets.

Comment: And that is not yet supported by GKE at least in Beta :(

Comment: Waiting for 1.5 on GKE

Comment: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/ page not found

Comment: The feature has been renamed to StatefulSets see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/